# Selenium select the first button that contains text matching

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using the Firefox webdriver for Selenium to scrape a webpage that looks to be rendered with React on the client side. The classes in the rendered DOM look dynamically generated, and seem to change with every new request. There are also many button elements on the page, some of which are not in the viewport. So my strategy is to search for a way to click on a button that contains text that I enter using selenium. Several buttons will contain the text, and I want to just find the first such button.

Using selenium/xpath, how would I select the first button that contained the text E9 1QJ?

```
<button>
    <div><svg ...> </div>
    <div>
        <div>London</div>
        <div>E9 1QJ</div>
    </div>
</button>

<button>
    <div><svg ...> </div>
    <div>
        <div>London Foo Bar</div>
        <div>E9 1QJ</div>
    </div>
</button>
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? With all the XPath and other locator tutorials on the web (along with questions on SO), surely you have read some by now and can hazard a handful of attempts? You will learn a lot less by asking for help before trying. Make sure you are using the dev console to test out locators instead of just plugging them into a script. That will allow you to iterate MUCH faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
{driver}.find_element_by_xpath("//button[div/div[text()='E9 1QJ']][1]")
```

But keep in mind that a solution like this it is not very flexible and could break with a minimum change in the html structure.